# Why does my pool pump keep tripping the breaker?

Tags: electrical

Please hang with me on this question and I hope I can explain it with enough detail to firgure out what is happening before hiring someone to come out and take a look.

I am not getting enough power to my pool pump outside.  I have tried reseting my circuit breaker multiple times and the rest of the house is still getting plenty of power but my pool pump still won't turn on or reset.  I have tried plugging in a radio to the electrical outlet connected to the pool pump to see if that will at least work but that will only work when I actually turn the pool on.  The pool pump still won't turn on but the radio will.  So I am getting enough power to turn the radio on when I turn the pool switch on but not enough to start the pool pump?  Shouldn't the electrical outlet work withought having the pool switch turned on?  And why does the radio only work when I have the pool on?  Sorry if that is the same question multiple times but I am very confused as to why this would be.  It feels like I am not gettting enough initial power to start the pool pump and because of that it trips everytime I turn the pool on.  Is this something that I can fix on my own?

Comment: What do you mean by "turn the pool on"? Does it do something fancy beyond holding a bunch of water?

Comment: Filter the water.  Sorry if that is turns you on.. perv.

Comment: What size breaker is the pool pump on? It should be listed on the breaker face or handle.

Comment: Did you recently make any changes (replace the switch, receptacle, pump, etc.)?

Comment: Haven't made any changes, but my dryer had a fuse blow the same day the pool pump stopped working.  I was able to get my dryer working again by resetting my circuit breaker but not the pool pump.

Comment: You'll likely have to contact a licensed Electrician. Troubleshooting electrical systems is very difficult to do without actually being onsite.

Comment: Breaker the pool pump is on.. I have narrowed it down to my main breaker for my house.  But I still can't figure out what 2 other breakers are on.. I do know with my pool filter on and my main breaker off my radio will not work.  So I am assuming it is the main.  When I get home I will tell you the exact size i think around 40 is that correct? Off the top of my head there are several 10's 20's and my main being a 40 on the handles.  Sorry if that is way off but I am pretty sure those are the numbers.  I will let you know exactly though when I get home.  Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @MarcusSteele Either you're not explaining things properly, or everything is completely FUBAR'd.  I don't think you're going to get useful advice here.  Call an electrician.

Comment: What Chris said.  You're in out of your depth and if you get things wrong it can kill you.  Please call an electrician or three and hire one who's willing to explain what you have to you before and while he's fixing it.

Comment: Something about this tells me you don't really understand how breakers work - and if that's the case, please call an electrician before you hurt yourself or others.  Electrical for wet locations like a pool needs to be done properly, or not at all.

Answer (score 6):

If the radio only comes on when the switch is on then you have a switched outlet, which is designed to only have power when the switch is on.

If the pump doesn't work when the switch is on, then since you already tried the radio on the outlet, and the radio worked, that means the problem is the pump itself.

If the pump is causing your breaker to trip, it indicates a SERIOUS problem with the pump causing a short circuit.  Stop trying to use the pump, it could be deadly.

Comment: Thanks Evil but have one more thing to add and I knew I was leaving something out.  The radio has worked plugged into that electrical outlet in the past without having the pool on. Does that make a difference, is this still an electrical issue or just a bad pump? thanks again.

Comment: So to confirm - in the past the radio worked with the pool off, now the radio doesn't work with the pool off ?

Comment: Exactly but does work now only when I turn on the the pool pump.  Thanks.

Comment: @MarcusSteele Is just one socket switched? How does the pump get turned off when you turn off the pool?

Comment: I have it on a timer.  But I can manually turn the pool off and on by the switch.  A silver switch that is right underneath the pool clock.  Flip it counter-clockwise to turn on the filter.  Clockwise to turn the filter off.